# Odontogram code

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to add an odontogram to my webpage.
It looks like this:

[image]

I would like to know if there is already some kind of open source odontogram.
I am using spring-mvc so it has to be in java

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?  Do you just need an image?  What kind of interactivity do you want?

Comment: Adding comments to each teeth and coloring it as it is shown in the image.

Comment: Please cite your image source: http://imagetooth.rubyforge.org/

Comment: @trashgod: You are right. my bad.

Comment: I suspect that you will not find an open source library for dentistry diagramming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's web based I'd think you'd just want to return an SVG from a servlet.

Answer (score 3):

If it must be interactive, I'd do this as an Applet or JWS application, with each tooth represented by an instance extending [`JComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) and containing five [`Polygons`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html). The latter would make filling and hit testing relatively easy. A simple data model containing *surface* (proximal, distal, lingual, labial, occlusal) and *color-code* would also be useful. See also [*ImageTooth*](http://imagetooth.rubyforge.org/).

Addendum: You may want to plan on consulting a subject matter expert regarding the clinical correlation of the numbers, colors and locations.